# Parent pages not found with pretty permalinks

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I'm building a site and for some reason all the parent pages are 404ing, only sub-level pages are displaying with pretty permalinks. If I use default permalinks, everything works fine.

I've tried disabling all the plugins & deleting htaccess and having Wordpress recreate the file, nothing works.

Any ideas?

Here's the site: http://www.855gotclog.com

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've sorted the site out. I had the same problem recently working on a Wordpress site someone else developed.

The issue was they had registered custom post types and taxonomies with Wordpress reserved slugs, like **year** and **term** for example. Also avoid registering custom post types and taxonomies that conflict with page or post slugs.

For example: creating a page named Portfolio and registering a custom post type portfolio.

`register_post_type('portfolio', $args );`

This will cause unexpected problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have saved me a headache five years later!